# Gsub in R for hyphens and digits

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `gsub` on the `df$Zipcode` in the following data frame:

```
#Sample
df <-data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               Zipcode =c("10001-2838", "95011", "95011", "100028018", "84321", "84321", "94011"))
df
```

I want to take everything after the "-" (hyphen) out and replace it with nothing. Something like:

```
df$Zipcode <- gsub("\-", "", df$Zipcode)
```

But I don't think that is quite right. I also want to take the first 5 digits of all Zipcodes that are longer than 5 digits, like observation 4. Which should just be 10002. Maybe this is correct:

```
df$Zipcode <- gsub("[:6:]", "", df$Zipcode)
```

Comment: so, just taking the first five characters of each string would solve the problem?

Comment: Ahh yes, that's true haha.

Comment: Like @Wimpel said, it seems like `substr(df$Zipcode,1,5)` would do the trick. No need for regular expresions

Comment: You need 2 backslashes (`\\\`) to escape, not 1

Answer (score 1):

We can capture the first 5 characters that are not a `-` as a group and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df$Zipcode <- sub("^([^-]{5}).*", "\\1", df$Zipcode)
df$Zipcode
#[1] "10001" "95011" "95011" "10002" "84321" "84321" "94011"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun but `substr(df$Zipcode,1,5)` did the trick.

Comment: @SamPickwick it would be different output with `substr` if there are values like `"1000-453"`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
sub("(\\d{5}).*", "\\1", df$Zipcode)
[1] "10001" "95011" "95011" "10002" "84321" "84321" "94011"
```

This matches the first 5 digits, puts them into a capturing group, and 'remembers' them (but not the rest) via backreference `\\1` in the replacement argument to `sub`.